# Is finding the number of solutions to a NP problem significantly harder than solving it?

Tags: boolean-algebra, np-complete, satisfiability

I am wondering what is known about the problem of finding the number of solution to a NP-complete problem. We can of course take SAT as an example, it doesn't matter that much. It is clear that this is harder than finding a solution to the problem and (equivalently) knowing if there is a solution or not. The problem that I see is that the number of solution may be very big, therefore any strategy of finding one, removing it with a clause and iterating is doomed.

Still it feels like this problem might be in the realm of NP problems. Indeed, the SAT that seems to be hard to handle are those that have a lot of solutions or very few solutions, which are not in general the hardest SATs. I was thinking about something like checking if for some variable $x_i$, one of $x_i\rightarrow C$, $\lnot x_i\rightarrow C$, $C\rightarrow x_i$ and $C\rightarrow\lnot x_i$ is true, which leads to a big reduction/augmentation in the number of solutions, then we can iterate using another pivot variable, but I do not know what is the worst case for this, probably something that is such that none of those are true every time we ask a question, which means that the number of solution is essentially moderate.

Anyways I would be interested in any literature on the subject, I couldn't find any.

Comment: Are you asking about problems that are NP-complete, NP-hard or in NP? And are you familiar with counting complexity classes like [#P](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E2%99%AFP)?

Comment: @A.M. Well I am asking about NP-complete problems, I edited the question. I think that #P describe exactly what I'm wondering about. Then I guess the answer to my question is not known then, right ?

Comment: If you do not demand the problem to be known to be hard, an example is very likely the problem how many divisors a given positive integer has. This is very probably much harder than to decide whether the given number is prime. Not sure whether it makes a significant difference if the decision whether a solution exists is already hard.